# Dataframe split columns value, how to solve error message?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe with the following columns:

```
             Stock     ROC5   ROC20  ROC63    ROCmean
        0    IBGL.SW  -0.59   3.55   6.57     3.18
        0    EHYA.SW   0.98   4.00   6.98     3.99
        0    HIGH.SW   0.94   4.22   7.18     4.11
        0    IHYG.SW   0.56   2.46   6.16     3.06
        0    HYGU.SW   1.12   4.56   7.82     4.50
        0    IBCI.SW   0.64   3.57   6.04     3.42
        0    IAEX.SW   8.34  18.49  14.95    13.93
        0    AGED.SW   9.45  24.74  28.13    20.77
        0    ISAG.SW   7.97  21.61  34.34    21.31
        0    IAPD.SW   0.51   6.62  19.54     8.89
        0    IASP.SW   1.08   2.54  12.18     5.27
        0    RBOT.SW  10.35  30.53  39.15    26.68
        0    RBOD.SW  11.33  30.50  39.69    27.17
        0    BRIC.SW   7.24  11.08  75.60    31.31
        0    CNYB.SW   1.14   4.78   8.36     4.76
        0     FXC.SW   5.68  13.84  19.29    12.94
        0   DJSXE.SW   3.11   9.24   6.44     6.26
        0  CSSX5E.SW  -0.53   5.29  11.85     5.54
```

How can I write in the dataframe a new columns "Symbol" with the stock without ".SW".
Example first row result should be IBGL (modified value IBGL.SW).
Example last row result should be CSSX5E (splited value SSX5E.SW).

If I send the following command:

```
new_df['Symbol'] = new_df.loc[:, ('Stock')].str.split('.').str[0]
```

Than I receive an error message:
:3: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
new_df['Symbol'] = new_df.loc[:, ('Stock')].str.split('.').str[0]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: As the msg show, it not an error msg, It is a warning msg. try `new_df = new_df .copy()` to avoid `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error, but a warning as you may have probably noticed your script finishes its execution.

edite: Given your comments it seems your issues generate previously in the code, therefore I suggest you use the following:

```
new_df = new_df.copy(deep=False)
```

And then proceed to solve it with:

```
new_df.loc['Symbol'] = new_df['Stock'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

Comment: I am getting the same warning message:
<ipython-input-5-82838e914b3c>:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  new_df['Symbol'] = new_df['Stock'].str.split('.').str[0]

Comment: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  isetter(ilocs[0], value)

Answer (score 1):

**METHOD 1:**

You can do a vectorized operation by `str.get(0)` -

```
df['SYMBOL'] = df['Stock'].str.split('.').str.get(0)
```

**METHOD 2:**

You can do another vectorized operation by using `expand=True` in `str.split()` and then getting the first column.

```
df['SYMBOL'] = df['Stock'].str.split('.', expand = True)[0]
```

**METHOD 3:**

Or you can write a custom `lambda` function with apply (for more complex processes). Note, this is slower but good if you have your own UDF.

```
df['SYMBOL'] = df['Stock'].apply(lambda x:x.split('.')[0])
```

Comment: Why would you use apply for a simple vectorized operation? It is inefficient.

Comment: with df['SYMBOL'] = df['Stock'].apply(lambda x:x.split('.')[0]), i am getting the same error message: python-input-92-81a2ba172e30>:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  new_df['SYMBOL'] = new_df['Stock'].apply(lambda x:x.split('.')[0])

Comment: I believe thats a warning not an error. Can you print your new_df to check if you are not getting that column as expected?

Answer (score 0):

```py
new_df = new_df.copy()
new_df['Symbol'] = new_df.Stock.str.replace('.SW','')
```

Comment: I am getting the same warning message:
<ipython-input-8-9e4fca09473f>:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  new_df['Symbol'] = new_df.Stock.str.replace('.SW','')